# NodeJS Parse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at Object.parse (native)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, file-read

I have a problem with my script and I'm beginner in Node.JS. I run **Ubuntu Linux**.

Problem details:

I have a script that writes a file (mini.json) many times per second. And another script that reads that file(mini.json) when the file changes. The problem is with the second script that reads the file.

**This is the app that reads the file**

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.locals.config.RandomData.forEach(function(item) {

fs.exists(item.random, function (exists) {
    if (exists) {

        var current_random_adress = item.random + '/mini.json';
        // console.log(current_random_adress);

        fs.watchFile(current_random_adress,{ persistent: true, interval: 1 }, function(curr,prev) {  // in ms
            // console.log("current mtime: " +curr.mtime);
            // console.log("previous mtime: "+prev.mtime);
            if (+curr.mtime === +prev.mtime) {

                // Do nothing because the file didn't change

            } else {
                console.log("The file have changes");

                var brute_data = fs.readFileSync(current_data, 'utf8');

                var object_parsed_from_file = JSON.parse(brute_data);


             //   console.log(object_parsed_from_file.random_string1);
                var datetime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');

            }
        });
        console.log("Route or file exists");
    } else {
        console.log("Route or file doesn't exist");
    }
});
```

});

**This is the file (readed with readFileSync)**

```
  {
"data1" : "random_string1",
"data2" : "random_string2",
"parities" : [
                {
                    "data3" : "random_string3",
                    "data4" : "random_string4",
                    "data5" : "random_string5"
                }
            ]
 }
```

**And this is the error.I outputed just the last 30 lines of the console**

Note: **The error occures after few thousand executions.**

```
The file have changes
random_string1 output
The file have changes
random_string1 output
The file have changes
random_string1 output
The file have changes
random_string1 output
The file have changes

undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at StatWatcher.<anonymous> (/media/idz/01D02FC315F350A0/Dev-    Node/microapp3/app.js:318:56)
at StatWatcher.emit (events.js:98:17)
at StatWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1115:10)
idz@idz-ThinkPad-Edge-E531:/media/idz/01D02FC315F350A0/Dev-Node/microapp3$
```